# wcf serialization inherited class error

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, abstract-class, datacontractserializer

we have two ***console application*** called "Frontend"(***FE***) and "Backend"(***BE***),

which are connected by ***WCF***. I need to have a ***abstract class*** and some

inherited classes in BE, at runtime I have instantiate an object from one of

the inherited classes by Activator.

whenever I want to return the instantiated object there is error related to

***serialization***. this is my simplified code

```
[DataContract]
public abstract class License
{

    [DataMember]
    public int ManagedObjectCount { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class LicenseMay2018 : License
{

    public Frontend.DataTypes.License GetLicenseInfo(xml xml)
    {
                    Frontend.DataTypes.LicenseMay2018 licenseVerified;
        var licXML = nodeData[0].InnerText;
        //Deserialize license
        XmlSerializer _serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(LicenseMay2018));
        using (StringReader _reader = new StringReader(licXML))
        {
            licenseVerified = (Frontend.DataTypes.LicenseMay2018)_serializer.Deserialize(_reader);
        }

    }

}

[DataContract]
public class LicenseApril2018 : License
{
}
```

on the BE side I return by type of the abstract class , expected to return the inherited class, every things works great by Activator and instantiating. The only problem is at the end of the method, when it wants to return to FE, seems to serialize and send back

```
public Frontend.DataTypes.License ActivateLicense(int LicenseFileId)
{
    // create in instance of inehrited class, no matter licensemay2018 or april2018 
    string assemblyName = "NMS.Common";
    var className = GetLicenseType(nodeVersion[0].InnerText);
    // exaple : className  = licensemay2018
    var handle = Activator.CreateInstance(assemblyName, className);
    var instance = (Frontend.DataTypes.License)handle.Unwrap();
    return instance.GetLicenseInfo(xmlDoc);
}
```

at run time I do not know about the exact type so I create the instance by type of the parent class, it works and the exact object is created

**at the time of returning there will be this error**

> There was an error while trying to serialize parameter
>   http://tempuri.org/:ActivateLicenseResult. The InnerException message
>   was 'Type 'NMS.Frontend.DataTypes.LicenseMay2018' with data contract
>   name
>   'LicenseMay2018:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/NMS.Frontend.DataTypes'
>   is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver if you are
>   using DataContractSerializer or add any types not known statically to
>   the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute
>   attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to the
>   serializer.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.

***I do not know where these comes from:  http://tempuri.org and http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07 ??***

Comment: There's nothing wrong with these namespaces. The one is used when you *don't* specify a namespace for your classes. The error says that an unexpected type was found. Where's the deserialization code? What does the full exception, including the call stack, look like? You can get it easily with `Exception.ToString()`. What does the *input* look like? How was it serialized? `Activator` has nothing to do with deserialization anyway.

Comment: BTW WCF isn't an XML serialization framework even though it uses the DataContractSerializer. You don't need to know the type, [DataContractSerializer.ReadObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.xmlobjectserializer.readobject(v=vs.110).aspx) returns an object

Comment: please see the edited GetLicenseInfo method, the deserialization works fine also for me

Comment: What does "works fine also" mean? You asked a question because it *doesn't* work. The error you posted is a *serialization* error. Post the code that throws and the actual exception.

Comment: Besides, the error message actually says that you should use `KnownType` or use a `DataContractResolver`

Comment: the problem solved by below answer, I did not know about knowntype and DataContractResolver approach! thats Why I asked this question thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the serializer about your inherited types. Add a KnownType attributes for your inhertied classes like this

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeOf(LicenseMay2018))]
[KnownType(typeOf(LicenseApril2018))]
public abstract class License
{

    [DataMember]
    public int ManagedObjectCount { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class LicenseMay2018 : License
{

    public Frontend.DataTypes.License GetLicenseInfo(xml xml)
    {
        return new licenseMay2018();
    }

}

[DataContract]
public class LicenseApril2018 : License
{
}
```